# Recompose does not trigger after mutableStateOf value changed

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to run different task by changing mutableStateOf mCurrentSplashTaskIndex. But Jetpack Compose recompose does not trigger after executeCurrentTask run to execut task1 in which mCurrentSplashTaskIndex changed to 1. The code is as below. Would you like to help me out? Thanks a lot.

```
class SplashViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val Tag = "SplashViewModel"
    private val mCurrentSplashTaskIndex = mutableStateOf(0)

    @Composable
    fun executeCurrentTask() {
        when (mCurrentSplashTaskIndex.value) {
            0 -> {
                Task1()
            }
            1 -> {
                Task2()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun Task1() {
        Log.d(Tag, "Task1 start...")
        findNextTask()
    }

    @Composable
    private fun Task2() {
        Log.d(Tag, "Task2 start...")
    }

    private fun findNextTask() {
        Log.d(Tag, "Find out next available task.")
        mCurrentSplashTaskIndex.value = mCurrentSplashTaskIndex.value + 1
        Log.d(Tag, "Got next available task ${mCurrentSplashTaskIndex.value}")
    }

}
```

Comment: There are no UI which need to be recomposed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Recompose also does not trigger even though UI Text had been added.
``
    @Composable
    fun executeCurrentTask() {
        Text(text = mCurrentSplashTaskIndex.value.toString())
        when (mCurrentSplashTaskIndex.value) {
            0 -> {
                Task1()
            }
            1 -> {
                Task2()
            }
        }
    }
``

Comment: In what circumstances you are using executeCurrentTask()?

Comment: Thanks for your comment again. I call viewModel.executeCurrentTask() in activity setContent.  setContent {
       val viewModel:SplashViewModel = viewModel()
       viewModel.executeCurrentTask()
}